# circulant matrix question

Tags: linear-algebra

could any one tell me what is translation? and if a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ commutes with all translation then must it be a circulant matrix? first please tell me the meaning of the question and then explain, please help, it was a question from a past year quals.thank you.

Comment: Does "the question" refer to the second of your two questions?

Answer (score 0):

Here a "*translation*" means a circulant shift operator of the form
$$(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T \mapsto (x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k)^T$$
for some $k$.